# Accessing Windows XP share from Windows 98

Tags: windows-xp, network-shares, windows-98

I have two computers. One running Windows XP Home, and another running Windows 98.

I recently had to reinstall Windows XP due to a crashed hard drive.

I am unable to access a share on the XP computer from the 98 computer, but I can access a share on the 98 computer from XP.

I was able to do this before the reload of XP, but I can’t figure out why it won’t work now.

I’m using IP addresses, so I know DNS is not the issue. I also have the firewall on XP turned off completely.

Answer (score 1):

Open Explorer on the XP box, go to Tools > Folder Options > View and then, in the Advanced Settings Pane, scroll down to the bottom of the list, tick the check box for "Use simple file sharing (Recommended)"